# Rails access information from a join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a rails app where I am using a join table to get a user lyrics and vice versa. For some odd reason I have not been able to get the count of a user lyrics. When I remove the through option from user model it works fine but I need it to work through shareships so users can share lyrics. Anyone had a similar problem or solution?

**User.rb**

```
has_many :shareships
has_many :lyrics, through: :shareships, dependent: :destroy
```

**Lyric.rb**

```
has_many :shareships
has_many :users, through: :shareships, dependent: :destroy
```

**Shareship.rb**

```
attr_accessible :lyric_id, :user_id

belongs_to :lyric
belongs_to :user
```

This is the code I am using in my view to display lyrics count

```
#Returns 0
<%= @user.lyrics.count %>
```

Comment: Associations look fine. Couple things: does the user simply have 0 lyrics? And what do your migrations look like? If its polymorphic theres a little more to be specified. Also, do you really want Lyrics destroying Users (dependent)?

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch data by using

```
<%= total_user_lyrics = @user.lyrics.count %>
```

If `user` doesn't have `lyrics` then it will return `0`. So that first check

**In your console**

`@user.lyrics` what it will return check it, if it will return nil then when you try `@user.lyrics.count` . you will get `0` because `@user.lyrics` have not records.

**Vice versa**

```
<%= total_lyric_users = @lyric.users.count %>
```

Comment: User has lyrics but I can only access them by removing the has_many :through association which I need in order for users to share lyrics. When I grab a lyric in the console then search for a user who owns the lyrics it works fine but when I try it vice versa nothing returns.

Comment: what you write for vice versa?

Comment: vice versa as in @lyric.user, it returns the user. I just found out that when I share a lyric with a user then the count increases.